# Pull data from separate DEs where there is a linked contact ID

Tags: ampscript

We use multiple data extensions for various different scenarios, but not all of them contain user information.

I need to send an email to users today where I'm sending to Data Extension B and this has the relevant contact ID, but not the user's first name, which exists in Data Extension A and is also mapped to the user's contact ID.

I want to pull the user's first name into the email body and I know I can write an AmpScript function for this, but I don't know how that works. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For Sure you would need to use AMPScript Lookup.It is little hard to explain via writing here. But I can point you to marketing cloud page which should give you enough idea to accomplish and the scenario mentioned on the page is similar to the one you have in hand.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/suggestedCarListings.htm

Comment: Biprajit, links change or get moved. Please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer so they stay here for reference.